# Running Launchd Services with Non Root User on macOS

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, launchd, macos-monterey, launchctl

I am building a launchctl service which can run a java service. I am able to create launchctl service with root user and test start/stop/status/automatic start at reboot use cases.

I am struggling with running same launchctl service with non root user(`ec2-user` in my case)

My `plist` file looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>siem</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>java</string>
    <string>-jar</string>
    <string>/Users/ec2-user/siem.jar</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/> <!-- run the program at login -->
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/> <!-- run the program again if it terminates -->
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/Users/ec2-user</string>
   <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
   <string>/tmp/mycommand.err</string>
   <key>StandardOutPath</key>
   <string>/tmp/mycommand.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have tried various steps to run the above service with `ec2-user`. UID for `ec2-user` is 501.

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-212 ~ % launchctl bootstrap gui/501 ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist
Bootstrap failed: 125: Unknown error: 125
```

Verified the content of plist file

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-212 ~ % plutil ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist
/Users/ec2-user/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist: OK
```

Tried bootstraping service with `user`

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-212 ~ % launchctl bootstrap user/501 ~/Library/LaunchDaemons/siem.plist
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
```

All of the above errors are not verbose and doesn't seem to find any way.

**My goal : I want to run launchctl service with non root user.**

**Environment Details:**

**OS** : macOS on AWS EC2 Instance

**macOS Version** : BigSur and Monterey

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm just learning about LaunchAgents, so I'm no expert. A MacOs agent/daemon may need elevated privileges.   Have you considered putting your `ec2-user` into the same user group `root` is in?   On my MBP, the other agents are owned by `root` with group `wheel`.  BTW, stackexchange.com is another place to ask your question.  It's for sysadmin  and devops type people.

Answer (score 2):

I just spent a significant time getting this to work, but it is complicated.

The `gui` domain is only available after a user has logged in with a graphical user session. Trying to add services to it when it is not available results in an error.

The `user` domain is available after a login (such as through SSH), but to add a service to this domain your .plist must contain the following key & value:

```
<key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
<string>Background</string>
```

If this key is not present, you get the dreaded "Input/output error", as the default value for this property is `Aqua` (ie. requires a GUI context). For more information about these session types see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html).

The problem is any of these services in the `user` domain do not get automatically started on reboot. The best solution to have a process running after reboot is to add them as root to the `system` domain and then add the `<UserName>` key to your .plist to run it as a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to run your launchd agent as a user do the following:

Instead of calling java directly in your `.plist` file, pass the command to shell. This ensures all environment variables which are necessary for java (like JAVA_HOME) are set. Also, use absolute paths:

```xml
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/bin/zsh</string>
  <string>-c</string>
  <string>java -jar /Users/ec2-user/siem.jar</string>
</array>
```

Next, I think your bootstrap command is wrong. I guess you have to use it like this:

```bash
launchctl bootstrap gui/"$(id -u)"/siem
```

To verify the agent starts successfully do

```bash
launchctl kickstart gui/"$(id -u)"/siem
```

Another good resource is https://launchd.info/